# MYSQL WHERE IN not working

Tags: php, mysql

MYSQL:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   invoice 
WHERE 'ID' IN('58,59,60,61,62,63,64,65,66,67,69,70,71,72,73,74,75,76,77,78,79,80,81,82,83,84,86,87,88,89,90,91,92,93,94,95,96,97,98,99,102,103,104,105,106,107,108,109,110,111,112,113,114,115,116,117,118,119,120,121,122,123,124,125,126,127,128,129,130,131,133,134,135,136,137,138,139,140,141,142,143,144,145,146,147,148,149,150,151,152,153,154,155')
```

All ID is in table invoice but it returning 0 rows anyone can please help me How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Just remove all '

Comment: Remove the quotes from ID.... Also you might wanna use `BETWEEN` instead of `IN` if it suits you. See https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_between.asp

Comment: @Leah no he can't use `BETWEEN` as far as some values are missing from the sequence. :)

Comment: If this is generated by PHP code then it might also be wise to share said code.

Comment: How are you generating these numbers for the ID? Do these come from another query? If they do can you give an example of it...

Answer (score 6):

You should pass an array to your IN function, please check the following link for more information: [MySQL IN](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/comparision-functions-and-operators/in-function.php)

Following query should work for you:

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM   
    invoice 
WHERE ID IN(58,59,60,61,62,63,64,65,66,67,69,70,71,72,73,74,75,76,77,78,79,80,81,82,83,84,86,87,88,89,90,91,92,93,94,95,96,97,98,99,102,103,104,105,106,107,108,109,110,111,112,113,114,115,116,117,118,119,120,121,122,123,124,125,126,127,128,129,130,131,133,134,135,136,137,138,139,140,141,142,143,144,145,146,147,148,149,150,151,152,153,154,155)
```

Alternatively you could use, if you have sequence of the given invoice-ids between 58 and 155:

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM   
    invoice 
WHERE ID BETWEEN 58 AND 155;
```

Answer (score 2):

Try This. remove '' in ID.

```
  SELECT * 
    FROM   invoice 
    WHERE 
    ID IN (58,59,60,61,62,63,64,65,66,67,69,70,71,72,73,74,75,76,77,78,79,80,81,82,83,84,86,87,88,89,90,91,92,93,94,95,96,97,98,99,102,103,104,105,106,107,108,109,110,111,112,113,114,115,116,117,118,119,120,121,122,123,124,125,126,127,128,129,130,131,133,134,135,136,137,138,139,140,141,142,143,144,145,146,147,148,149,
150,151,152,153,154,155)
```

Answer (score 1):

when you're passing:

```
IN('58,59,60,61,62,63,64,65,66,67,69,70,71,72,73,74,75,76,77,78,79,80,81,82,83,84,86,87,88,89,90,91,92,93,94,95,96,97,98,99,102,103,104,105,106,107,108,109,110,111,112,113,114,115,116,117,118,119,120,121,122,123,124,125,126,127,128,129,130,131,133,134,135,136,137,138,139,140,141,142,143,144,145,146,147,148,149,150,151,152,153,154,155')
```

the query engine is trying to look for

```
'58,59,60,61,62,63,64,65,66,67,69,70,71,72,73,74,75,76,77,78,79,80,81,82,83,84,86,87,88,89,90,91,92,93,94,95,96,97,98,99,102,103,104,105,106,107,108,109,110,111,112,113,114,115,116,117,118,119,120,121,122,123,124,125,126,127,128,129,130,131,133,134,135,136,137,138,139,140,141,142,143,144,145,146,147,148,149,150,151,152,153,154,155'
```

as a string. Although you have all these IDs, but they're available separately, not as a concatenated string.

Remove the `'` within the bracket and it should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
FROM   invoice 
WHERE `ID` IN(58,59,60,61,62,63,64,65,66,67,69,70,71,72,73,74,75,76,77,78,79,80,81,82,83,84,86,87,88,89,90,91,92,93,94,95,96,97,98,99,102,103,104,105,106,107,108,109,110,111,112,113,114,115,116,117,118,119,120,121,122,123,124,125,126,127,128,129,130,131,133,134,135,136,137,138,139,140,141,142,143,144,145,146,147,148,149,150,151,152,153,154,155)
```

Comment: This will not work, you are passing a string, which should be an array

Answer (score 0):

In your query you are asking to check whether  the string `'ID'` is in that list or not,

and you want to check weather the column `ID`'s value matching with the list items or not. for that you need to pass `ID` and list values without quotes , quotes makes it string literal so use,

```
SELECT * 
FROM   invoice 
WHERE ID IN(58,59,60,61,62,63,64,65,66,67,69,70,71,72,73,74,75,76,77,78,79,80,81,82,83,84,86,87,88,89,90,91,92,93,94,95,96,97,98,99,102,103,104,105,106,107,108,109,110,111,112,113,114,115,116,117,118,119,120,121,122,123,124,125,126,127,128,129,130,131,133,134,135,136,137,138,139,140,141,142,143,144,145,146,147,148,149,150,151,152,153,154,155)
```